# How to use a different model to deep neural network with reinforcement learning based on DQN?

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, unsupervised-learning, deep-learning

Is it possible to implement a reinforcement learning algorithm without using a deep neural network (DNN) as used in deep reinforcement learning e.g. Deep Q-Network (DQN)?

How can I replace the DNN in the DQN algorithm with another algorithm? Should it be supervised or unsupervised, and what is this called - is it  "un/supervised reinforcement learning" or "un/supervised DQN"?

In the following DQN pseudo-code, if I want to replace a DNN section with another un/supervised algorithm, is it possible? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: Thanks I edit the topic what I mean is the un/supervised reinforcement learning!

Comment: That makes sense. So you are asking if it is possible to replace the "deep" part of DQN with some other model? I will try to tidy that up without changing the meaning?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace DNN section of DQN with a supervised or unsupervised learning approach? Is it possible? How?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace DNN section of DQN with a supervised or unsupervised learning approach? Is it possible?If yes, How?                                                            Also the method is not any more DQN it will be supervised Q-Net or a unsupervised Q-Net! What you put in the title guides to a misunderstanding

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title back to avoid misunderstanding. It was my best guess. But you want to avoid using the phrase "un/supervised reinforcement learning" because it does not mean anything (I've left it in the body of your question so that someone can answer and tell you that)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you remove the DNN, I would not call that a Deep Q-Network anymore.. but it is definitely possible to remove that and still consider the approach as Reinforcement Learning.

Actually, the function of the deep neural network is just to approximate the Q-value function. The DNN is just a function in the form $Q_\theta(s, a)$ and based on samples, you adjust $\theta$ to minimize the error.

In practice, you could use any function you want. Obviously, some functions will work better than others. There are simpler approaches based on linear regression, least squares, kernel-based approaches, etc.

With respect to unsupervised learning.. mm. I guess you could force it somehow, but keep in mind that it would not totally make sense given that RL already provides you feedback so it makes sense that you use it.

Some interested advantage of neural networks is that they can find common elements in $\phi$ and rapidly abstract away some noise that if is not relevant with respect to predicting the Q-value of certain state/action.

I noticed that you would like to use something like random forests, etc. There is nothing to stop you from doing that. In particular, random forests are not ideal because they don't deal well with non-stationary. Instead they require bit batches of data. However, this does not mean, it is impossible.

In DQN, after you sample from the environment, you obtain feedback from the environment in the form of rewards associated with state/action pairs. RL combines this information with previous predictions using TD (there are some variations like TD($\lambda$), etc.). What TD gives you is a better estimate of $Q(s,a)$ and your predictor (in this case, your random forest) should learn that when the input is $(s,a)$ the correct answer is $Q(s,a)$.

It is likely that you've seen the same inputs before (specially for initial states) but because TD improves the reference value, you would need to drop these previous values and replace them with the most recent ones. Random forest would need to get this whole batch again.

In general, I accept that while both cases are supervised learning, adjusting DQN to work with non-parametric methods such as random forests can be inconvenient.

If I had to guess based on the comments, I think your main question circles around the distinction between parametric and non-parametric supervised learning. In that case, it is fair to say that most non-parametric methods are not easy to combine with DQN.

Comment: Thanks but I think there is misunderstanding! I know this is not a DQN it is a un/supervised reinforcement (un/supervised q-learning)!                                   Does this make sense if we replace DNN with a supervised or unsupervised learning approach? I think we could not replace DNN with a supervised learning approach in DQN because there is no true label for it!                                        
 Also, we could not use unsupervised learning instead of DNN in a DQN approach because of being MDP! Am I right? or we could? If we could how?

Comment: The "true label" is the Q(s,a) value that you want to predict. Think of supervised learning for continuous functions. From the perspective of DNN, you are using supervised learning and you want to approximate the Q function as well as possible.

Comment: But I do not think this is True! If you take a look at algorithm of DQN I presented above there is no training data therefore we can not replace a DNN section of DQN with a supervised learning! If you still insist on being able to replace with a supervised learning and there is no training data available! what you put for that? I do not ever seen a paper used a supervised Q-learning or a unsupervised Q-learning! Do you know a paper in this field?

Comment: Sorry, but I am sure about this. The training data is produced by the environment. The agent receives feedback from the environment, uses a TD update and the sampled Q value is compared with the predicted Q value. That is when the supervised learning happens. Almost any RL paper that uses a function approximator requires supervised learning. If you want a more explicit description look for any actor-critic configuration.

Comment: What I mean by supervised reinforcement learning is random forest Q-learning and SVR Q-learning! I do not see anything in this field? Have you ever seen about this! If you are sure please say me what I put for training data of random forest or SVR in deep learning section of DQN code!

Comment: @user10296606: purpletentacle is correct, the DNN inside the RL algorithm is being used in a *supervised* learning approach, predicting Q values once it has been shown some. Experience replay is used for the training data, with one key difference from normal supervised learning data sets: The target labels are generated on demand by the RL algorithm.

Comment: @user10296606 you could use any supervised approach you want, that is not a problem. In any case, you will always be learning the Q-value function.  Your training data will be available in your replay memory, however, due to the stochastic nature of the environments it is good if you batch the data. In addition, due to non-stationarity, TD updates are necessary.

Comment: @user10296606: You are right that you don't see RF or SVR used in Q-learning very often. It *is* possible in theory, but both those algorithms have a weakness when it comes to using them in RL - they do not work well against online, non-stationary datasets, whilst neural networks do.

Comment: Look at sutton's book. Older examples show how to do RL with simpler function approximators like linear regression, minimum squares, etc.

Comment: @NeilSlater well, actually it was a bit of a surprise for the community that neural networks did work. Q-Learning was previously known to converge with least squares only.

Comment: Thanks Neil, If you look at my question https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37633/is-nn-with-no-hidden-layer-is-behave-like-a-regression/37641#37638                                                       I am asking about it! What is confusing for me is that I have no true label data and reinforcement learning is not consider as a supervised or unsupervised learning approach!but for a no hidden layer network

Comment: ( 2 layers:1- input,2-output it is similar to regression however there is no true label). Every NN is not a supervised learning some of them are supervised and some of them are unsupervised learning one!And NN used in DQN do not have any label so it is not a supervised! If you are insisting on your approach consider a RF_QN how you say about training data in a experience replay! Sometime DQN works without experience replay! What is your answer for it!

Comment: @user10296606: I don't want to debate you at length in the comments. This answer is correct, so are comments by purpletentacle. If you still don't understand or disagree, then ask a new question specifically about that (e.g. "Is the neural network in DQN used to learn like a supervised model?")

Comment: I would recommend you to look at Sutton's or Kevin Murphys' books. DQN is about using supervised learning to approximate the Q-value function. You use a loss function based on the square error between the prediction and the current TD update. Supervised learning is not about discrete "labels" is about having a loss function that you use to compare predictions with known values. In this case, those are sampled from the environment. I see you struggle with seeing how to combine random forest with RL. Maybe you can open another question about that.

Comment: @purpletentacle which chapters of which version of this book said this?